# Android Tablet running out of internal memory

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, internal

In my company we have recently had a big internal memory issue with many of our Android tablets. We are not sure if its a software or hardware issue and this is the reason I´m asking:

These tablets completly ran out of internal memory, in Settings the OS says that there is 0MB left of internal memory. Of course everything crashes in this state, since Android can´t create services, databases or anything else.

The question is, can this be caused by a leak in one of the apps we use? Is Android prepared to clean up part of this internal memory in case such a leak occurs? If this could be a memory leak, how can we check it out? I´ve checked the posts about reading the internal memory, but I couldnt figure out if having root acces gives you the ability to do that, and if so, how would it be done.

We are a big client of the tablet company so we can manage to have this root access.

Thanks very much in advance for any help,

Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin using the mat http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ from eclipse and try to figure if it's an application that is leaking. The other thing to do is to make your app use large heap setting to run if it requires a lot of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pasquale. I´ve had a look at tha application and it´s pretty nice, we´ll start using it to analyze possible leaks. We finally found the source of our troublesome, it was a third party tracking app we were using. So we´re very relieved it wasn´t us. Thanks again.